# How to start new Activity by clicking button on html page loaded in webview?

Tags: android

I want to start an Activity by clicking button on html page which has been loaded in webview. I tried following code to  load webview instance with html file and create an interface so that it can be accessed using javascript from html page.

```
public void UpdateWebViewClientWithURL(String url)
{ 
WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSetings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new CommonLibrary(this.getApplicationContext()),    "Android"); 

myWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Javascript in html page looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast() {
        Android.launchActivity();
    }
</script>
```

Now in CommonLibrary class file , I have following function define to lunch new Activity

```
public void launchActivity()
{
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, testactivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

With all these setting i am seeing every time i click the button, the application is crashing. I know there is way but i searched every possible way , can anyone please help me understand as what is wrong here or how can i achieve this with simple example ?
Appreciate your help and time !

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: can you post the log of the application crashing? maybe the reason for crashing is in there